# Unable to run completely sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign http: packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu InRelease
......

Err http: packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu/quantal Sources                
  503  Service Unavailable
....................          
Ign http://packages.mate-desktop.org quantal/main Translation-en
```

100% [Logging in]
This will run for a very long time and won't stop.

Answer (score 0):

You added an unsupported third party repository that is now broken. Disable it.